# Call ICollection in ICollection with Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I want a lambda expression, that when i call a *Company* from database with id 1030 to bring me Companys info, a list with all the *cars* that company has and a list of all *images* that related to each car (each car has 4 images).

*Structure of my classes*:

```
public partial class Companies
    {
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Tel { get; set; }
        public string Logo { get; set; }
        public int? Owner { get; set; }
        public int? Address { get; set; }
        public int? Publish { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Cars> Cars { get; set; }
}
public partial class Cars
    {

        public int CarId { get; set; }
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal? Price { get; set; }
        public int? CarCatId { get; set; }
        public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
        public int? CharacteristicId { get; set; }

        public ICollection<CarImages> CarImages { get; set; }
}

public partial class CarImages
    {
        public int CarImagesId { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public int? CarId { get; set; }

        public Cars Car { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see in *Company* class, I have a reference to *Cars* class as ICollection, and the same thing in *Cars* class with *CarImages*.

I've try lot of things including those:

```
var compInfo = _context.Companies.SelectMany(cr => cr.Cars.SelectMany(i =>i.CarImages.Where(car => car.CarId == car.Car.CarId))).ToList();

var compInfo2 = _context.Companies.Include(a => a.AddressNavigation).Include(cr =>cr.Cars.).FirstOrDefault(c => c.CompanyId == id);
```

The 2nd brings me the info of company (and it's address) and the list of the cars (which is the half success) but not the images..

The 1st just brings me a list all the info of images table.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Please edit your question to use actual text instead. Just copy-paste the code directly into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
//Get the Company with id == 1030.
    var x = _context.Companies.Include(a => a.AddressNavigation).Include(c => c.Cars).Where(c => c.CompanyId == id).FirstOrDefault();

//Get the Car ICollection and include the CarImages ICollection depending on CompanyID. 
    var y = _context.Cars.Include(img => img.CarImages).Where(cr => cr.CompanyId == x.CompanyId).ToList();

//Now each Car in our Cars list has a list of CarImages related to each car. Finaly pass our data to our Company var(x) and send it to View.
    x.Cars = y;
    return View(x);
```